# How to create a YTD model based measure in SAC

Tags: cloud, analytics, sap-analytics-cloud

I have a finance model but having difficulty creating a YTD model based measure. See below model set up.
There is no option to add measure

[image: finance model]

Thanks

I did successfully create a YTD model based measure in another model, but the option to add a new measure is greyed out. As system owner I would not think permissions is an issue.